# Android Tab inside fragment containing simple views

Tags: android, user-interface, tabs, android-fragments

I have read some examples, tutorials, question on stackoverflow, but till now I don't think
it's quite clear if what I want to do should be simpler or done anyway!

I will post a draft design for better understanding.

[image]

As you can see I just need to have a fragment like the above which will inflated by an Activity and this fragment should contain some custom compound controls and other simple Views.

Now I need as you can see on the left of the draft a Tab (control) which will simply contain Views into each tab area and interact with them through the fragment.
I think its so redundant using different activity for every tab or even different fragment.

I thought of a solution with buttons and visible/hide views.

Any examples, tutorials solving such a problem welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create buttons in place of tabs and you can just change the

```
                setContentView(yourlayout)
```

accordingly Example

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.tab1:

        setContentView(R.layout.tab1); 
                                              // perform other changes if needed
        break;

    case R.id.tab2:
        setContentView(R.layout.tab2);
        break;

    case R.id.tab3:

        setContentView(R.layout.tab3);
        break;
   }
```

this will be useful if you have minimum level of functionality to perform

Comment: Thanx for answering but this will replace my whole fragment contentView! I just need a specific area to get replaced. Its an easy workaround but not suitable I guess for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: you can also use viewFlipper where oly certain area will get updated you can toggle between the views

Comment: Will check this viewFlipper. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of achieving this. You could use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) + [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/). Or display the content as separate Fragments in a FrameLayout, and replace it with [FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#Replace)'s when user selects a different tab. One bonus with the ViewPager implementation is that the user can swipe between the different tabs.